# How to call multiple methods or controllers to a same route in laravel

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

Find below the controller code with two methods and suggest me how to call these two methods in the same route or whether I have to create two different controllers for the same page(route).

```
class TicketController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){
    $results=Whmcs::GetTickets([

    ]);
    return view('clientlayout.main.index',compact('results'));
}

    public function set(){
    $test=Whmcs::GetInvoices([

    ]);
    return view('clientlayout.main.index',compact('test'));
}
```

}

The route file:

```
  Route::get('clientlayout.main.index','TicketController@show');

  Route::get('clientlayout.main.index','TicketController@set');
```

Find the code in the blade file and after running this I'm getting an error

> undefined index:Results.

```
  @foreach($results['tickets']['ticket'] as $key)

  {{$key['subject']}}
  @endforeach



  @foreach($test['invoices']['invoice'] as $value)

  {{$value['firstname']}}
  @endforeach
```

When I run these two foreach loops in a different blade file it executes correctly, but I need these two results to be viewed in the same file.

How to view both tickets and invoices in the same index page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the two controllers into one and perform both queries in a single method:

```
class InvoiceTicketController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){
        $tickets = Whmcs::GetTickets([]);
        $invoices = Whmcs::GetInvoices([]);
        return view('clientlayout.main.index',compact('tickets', 'invoices'));
    }
}
```

Then update one of the those routes to use the combined controller:

```
Route::get('clientlayout.main.index','InvoiceTicketController@show');
```

You'll have access to both `$tickets` and `$invoices` collections in the blade file this way:

```
@foreach($tickets as $ticket)
  {{ $ticket->subject }}
@endforeach

@foreach($invoices as $invoice)
  {{ $invoice->firstname }}
@endforeach
```